# Slow Query on Wordpress Search

Tags: wordpress

Please I have a very slow query on my wordpress search, checking the processes it takes upto 40sec to execute using `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` below is a sample of query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Industreet%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%Industreet%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Industreet%')))  AND (wp_posts.post_password = '')  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Industreet%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

I have tried my best to fix this, but nothing is working out. though I have a total post of 120k on my site. I really need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did You have Redis tech. on Your server for caching DB tables and results? Also You can try to add filters for search before execute search, example, user must chose in which category of blog want to search('cars', 'animals' etc.). In this way, search will be more easy to system, cause it will be smaller amount of posts to search(not in absolutely 120k of posts).

Comment: I dont have redis tech. on the other hand, on wp I have checked there is no function for searching post by category, Please can you refer me to one ?

Comment: For start, You can try to use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-filter-search/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/ with short codes. On other hand, if You need specific look and filters, it can be provide by custom code(example read here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/advanced-wordpress-search-with-wp_query/ or You can search in Google "create custom search wordpress"). All the all, i highly recommend install, configure and connect Redis if You have your own server.

Comment: I am on a vps unmanged. so how do I install redis, this is the first time I am hearing about it...